# How to free double pointers after usage in c?

Tags: c, malloc, free

```
float **tree0;

tree0 = (float**)malloc(255 * sizeof(float*));

for( i = 0; i < 255; i++) 
    tree0[i] = (float*)malloc(M * sizeof(float));
for(i = 0; i < 255; i++)
    for( k = 0; k < M; k++)
        tree0[i][k] = 2;
```

Should I just free it like this

```
free(tree0);
```

I am heap corruption errors somewhere and thought this might be the problem...

Comment: Heap corruption *might* be a result of casting the return of `malloc` but not from the fact that you are not freeing some memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `free()` as many times as you called `malloc()` and on the same addresses which was returned by `malloc()`. So, You just do it the way you allocated it:

```
for( i = 0; i < 255; i++) 
    free(tree0[i])

free(tree0);
```

Comment: should I always call free? If a have a method and a local pointer in it, won't the pointer be freed automatically after the method has been called?

Answer (score 1):

For every `malloc()` there must be a `free()`. You need to iterate in the same fashion as the `malloc()` loop but call `free(tree0[i])` and then `free(tree0)` afterwards.

Note that casting the return value from `malloc()` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Every `malloc` need a `free`, so you'll need a similar `for` loop to free all the inner mallocs.